# How combine normal and reduce cells in Darts (NAS)

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, nas, automl

We use Darts a library of nnabla-nas to create the model but as results we obtained a arch.json file where we don't understand how is the real shape of the model.

We want find a solution to understand the layers of the model.
we also have pictures of reduction cells and normal cells but is not clear how those cells are used in the final architecture.

```
{
    "normal_alpha": {
        "2": [
            [
                2,
                1
            ],
            [
                0,
                0
            ]
        ],
        "3": [
            [
                3,
                2
            ],
            [
                2,
                1
            ]
        ],
        "4": [
            [
                3,
                0
            ],
            [
                2,
                3
            ]
        ],
        "5": [
            [
                2,
                0
            ],
            [
                1,
                2
            ]
        ]
    },
    "normal_prob": {
        "2": [
            0.13768738508224487,
            0.13445907831192017
        ],
        "3": [
            0.14307735860347748,
            0.1389739066362381
        ],
        "4": [
            0.1398751139640808,
            0.1376882642507553
        ],
        "5": [
            0.1424567848443985,
            0.14037831127643585
        ]
    },
    "normal_choice": {
        "1": 2,
        "0": 0,
        "4": 3,
        "3": 2,
        "2": 7,
        "5": 3,
        "8": 2,
        "7": 7,
        "6": 7,
        "9": 2,
        "11": 1,
        "12": 7,
        "13": 7,
        "10": 7
    },
    "reduce_alpha": {
        "2": [
            [
                3,
                1
            ],
            [
                0,
                0
            ]
        ],
        "3": [
            [
                1,
                2
            ],
            [
                3,
                1
            ]
        ],
        "4": [
            [
                0,
                0
            ],
            [
                0,
                1
            ]
        ],
        "5": [
            [
                0,
                4
            ],
            [
                6,
                1
            ]
        ]
    },
    "reduce_prob": {
        "2": [
            0.13325053453445435,
            0.1294509321451187
        ],
        "3": [
            0.1414458155632019,
            0.13497161865234375
        ],
        "4": [
            0.14355652034282684,
            0.13150085508823395
        ],
        "5": [
            0.1437295377254486,
            0.13777314126491547
        ]
    },
    "reduce_choice": {
        "1": 3,
        "0": 0,
        "4": 1,
        "3": 3,
        "2": 7,
        "5": 0,
        "6": 0,
        "7": 7,
        "8": 7,
        "13": 0,
        "10": 6,
        "12": 7,
        "9": 7,
        "11": 7
    }
}
```